How to calculate the area enclosed by $ a(x^2+1)(y^2+1) = 2(a^2+1)xy $ in the region where $x>0$ and $y>0$
I attempted to convert the curve into polar coordinates and obtained the following results:
$$ r^4(\sin{\theta} \cos{\theta})^2 + r^2 + 1 = \frac{2(a^2+1)}{a}r^2\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}   $$
Further simplification yields:
$$ \frac{r^4}{4} \sin^2{2\theta} + r^2 + 1 = \frac{(a^2+1)}{a}r^2 \sin{2\theta} $$
I don't have any ideas on how to proceed from here. I'm unsure how to continue. Should I use Vieta's formulas to force a solution for $ r^2 $. This approach doesn't seem right.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

$(x+\frac1x)(y+\frac1y)=2(a+\frac1a)$.  Key points are $(1,a),(1,1/a),(a,1),(1/a,1)$

Start by solving the quadratic equation in $r^2 \sin 2\theta =f(r).$ Integration limits $( 0-\pi/4)$ due to symmetry with $x=y$ line.

Empy2's hint means $$\cosh u \ \cosh v < \cosh a$$ by $x\to e^u, y\to e^v$ yielding $$\int (\text{Boole}(\cosh u \ \cosh v < \cosh a)) dx \wedge dy=2 a \int_{-a}^a \text{sech} \ s \ ds$$

@Empy2 Thank you for your response. I didn't realize it could be simplified this way. This definitely seems like the right direction.

@RolandF I think that should be $\ldots < \cosh \log a$.

Assume $a \geq 1$. (The curve has no points if $a < 0$, for $a = 0$ it is the union of the coordinates axes, and for $a > 0$, it is invariant under the replacement $a \mapsto \frac1a$.) For $a > 1$ the curve is elliptic$^*$, so I don't think we should expect a nice closed form in terms of elementary functions.
Solving for $y$ gives
$$y = \frac{1}{a (1 + x^2)} \left((1 + a^2) x \pm \sqrt{(a - x) (a + x) (1 - a x)(1 + a x)}\right), $$
so the area $A_a$ enclosed by the curve is the integral of the difference of the $\pm$ expressions on the right-hand side:
$$A_a = \frac{2}{a} \int_{\frac1a}^a \frac{\sqrt{(a - x) (a + x) (1 - a x)(1 + a x)}}{1 + x^2} \,dx .$$ As is usually the case, the appearance of a quartic under a radical portends the requirement of elliptic functions to express the integral:
\begin{multline*}A_a =
- \frac2a K\left(\frac{\sqrt{a^4 - 1}}{a^2}\right)
- 2 a E\left(\frac{\sqrt{a^4 - 1}}{a^2}\right) \\
+ \frac{2 (1 + a^2)}{a^3} \Pi\left(1 - \frac1{a^2}, \frac{\sqrt{a^4 - 1}}{a^2}\right),
\end{multline*}
where $K, E, \Pi$ are the complete elliptic functions of the first, second, and third kinds, respectively.
As $a \to 1$, the area behaves asymptotically as
$$A_a = \pi (a - 1)^2 + \cdots,$$
where $\cdots$ denotes terms of order $O((a - 1)^3)$, which reflects the fact that for $a$ just larger than $1$ the curve is approximately a circle of radius $a - 1$ centered at $(1, 1)$.
As $a \to \infty$, the area behaves asymptotically as
$$A_a = 2 a \log a + \cdots,$$ where $\cdots$ denotes terms of order $O(a)$.
$^*$In fact, we can compute the $j$-invariant explicitly: $j = \frac{16 (a^8 + 14 a^4 + 1)^3}{(a + 1)^4 a^4 (a - 1)^4 (a^2 + 1)^4}$, which is $\geq 1728$ for real $a$.

Thank you for your patient explanation, Professor Willse. I originally encountered this problem in a math interest group. The original question is to find the area enclosed by the curve in the region where $x>0$ and $y>0$, denoted as $S(a)$. The final goal is to determine the limit $\lim_{a \to \infty} \left( \frac{S(a)-2aln(a)}{2} \right)$. Your answer is correct. Thank you very much.

You're welcome. You might be interested in this related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4849459/155629

Have you scaled $y$?  I think the average of the two roots should be $x(a^2+1)/(a(x^2+1))$.

@Empy2 You're right---there was a missing parenthesis somewhere. Thanks for pointing out the issue (which was just typographical, the rest of the answer is unaffected). I've corrected the relevant equations.
